# File in the same path, one can be git trace but others cannot

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git repo at path `dir_a`, and I have a file that I want to trace it at `dir_a/dir_b/dir_c/memory.cpp`. But I can't trace it, when I try to add it `git add ./dir_b/dir_c/memory.cpp` , it will announce me :

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
dir_b
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
```

I have check my `.gitignore` file in `dir_a` and `dir_b`, but I don't understand why my whilelist cannot work. My `.gitignore` file as follows:

```
#dir_a/.gitignore

*.*
*
!/dir_b/*
```

```
#dir_b/.gitignore

*.*
*
!*.cpp
```

And I had try to figure out which file results into this situation, and the output is as follows:

```
% git check-ignore -v ./dir_b/dir_c/memory.cpp
.gitignore:2:*  ./dir_b/dir_c/memory.cpp

% git check-ignore -v ./dir_b/dir_c/main.cpp
```

It looks like it can trace my `main.cpp` but cannot trace another file in the same path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [gitignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)...

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

`*` has ignored everything at the top-directory (`*.*` is unnecessary) including dir_b. You need to restore dir_b.

`!/dir_b/*` restores what's in dir_b, but not dir_b itself. You also need to restore dir_b with `!/dir_b/`.

One more issue. `!/dir_b/*` only restores what's in dir_b. `*` does not match a `/`; it does not restore subdirectories. For example, dir_b/subidr/foo will not be restored. For that you need `!/dir_b/**`, `**` matches everything.

```
*

# Restore dir_b/
!/dir_b/

# Restore everything in dir_b/
!/dir_b/**
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have solved this problem!

Comment: @MollyZheng I had a chance to test it, it was incorrect. Now it's correct and tested.

Comment: Actually, in my test, `!/dir_b/` can make me trace everything in my path `dir_b`. I have used `!/dir_b/**` and I cleaned my cache,  `./dir_b/dir_c/main.cpp` is not traced anymore.

Comment: @MollyZheng You need both `!/dir_b/` and `!/dir_b/**`. `git-check-ignore` seems to be giving inconsistent results and claims that `!/dir_b/**` ignores dir_b and what's inside it. [Demonstration](https://gist.github.com/schwern/50391d37d6c32a2959e97f42409286e9)

Comment: @MollyZheng Note that `git check-ignore -v` appears to have a bug. It changes the exit status even if none of the files are ignored.

Comment: You can use `git rm --cached .`  to delete cached files

Comment: When I use both `!/dir_b/` and `!/dor_b/**` , `git check-ignore` gives the same result that `dir_b/file` can be traced. And when I only use `!/dir_b/` also have the same result.

Comment: @MollyZheng Are you using `git check-ignore` or `git check-ignore -v`? They act differently. `git check-ignore` will only show a file if it's ignored. `git check-ignore -v` will show a file if it matches any pattern, including negative patterns like `!/dir_b/`. It's confusing. You'll see something like `dir_b/file:!/dir_b/**` which means `dir_b/file` is not ignored.

Comment: Yes, when I using `!/dir_b/ !/dir_b/**`, command `% git check-ignore -v ./dir_b/dir_c/memory.cpp` and command `%git check-ignore -v ./dir_b/dir_c/memory.cpp` , neither of them produced any output.